# Empty output with GPS module GTPA010

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, gps

I've synced my Uno with the Arduino IDE and I'm using the following code to get the GPS coordinates:

```
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

unsigned long fix_age;
SoftwareSerial GPS(4,3);
TinyGPS gps;
void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);
bool feedgps();
void getGPS();
long lat, lon;
float LAT, LON;

void setup(){
  GPS.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  long lat, lon;
  unsigned long fix_age, time, date, speed, course;
  unsigned long chars;
  unsigned short sentences, failed_checksum;
  // retrieves +/- lat/long in 100000ths of a degree
  gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &fix_age);
  // time in hh:mm:ss, date in dd/mm/yy

  getGPS();
  Serial.print("Latitude : ");
  Serial.print(lat/100000,7); //#UPDATED
  Serial.print(" :: Longitude : ");
  Serial.println(lon/100000,7); //#UPDATED
}

void getGPS(){
  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();
  // Every 1 seconds we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 1000)
  {
    if (feedgps ()){
      newdata = true;
    }
  }
  if (newdata)
  {
    gpsdump(gps);
  }
}

bool feedgps(){
  while (GPS.available())
  {
    if (gps.encode(GPS.read()))
      return true;
  }
  return 0;
}

void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  //byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
  Serial.print("Hello World : "); //#UPDATED (Test)
  LAT = lat;
  LON = lon;
  {
    feedgps(); // If we don't feed the gps during this long
  }
}
```

When I compile, it uploads successfully and when I check the serial streams, it displays:

Latitude : 41103 :: Longitude : 41103

But my lat/lon (in the risk of disclosing location) is 
(38.984898400, -76.957276900)

It doesn't seem to be the same.

Comment: is the GPS getting a good view of the sky?   Should add some prints to see if you are getting into gpsdump()   or just print your lat/lon rather then reassigning it to LAT/LON

Comment: @ChadG: I've kept it on a wide window sill with a view. So I guess that should work. Surprisingly, now it's even displaying garbage like 

⸮7C⸮wyCCZVa⸮HR-⸮K=LR3⸮(⸮:⸮xk;GqB⸮9Jb⸮j

I added some prints inside the gpsdump(). Nothing happens, so I'm not even sure if it's getting into it.

Comment: Can you update the code and provide the output

Comment: @ChadG: I updated the code and results.

Comment: Actually update the code in the question, its to hard to go back and forth between your original code and the comment.   Did you ever try the GPS baud rate of 4800?

Comment: @ChadG: I did just now. No change in the lat/lon. Also if I change the baud rate from 9600 in the serial monitor, it again outputs garbage.

Comment: You have control of both sides of the serial monitor speed.   The drop down in the serial monitor needs to match the speed that is in the Serial.begin() function.   The GPS.begin() needs to match what the gps is outputting. (which is usually fixed and not changable)    I would print the data received from the gps directly to the console, no need to try and process it until you are sure your getting good data from the GPS. The strings coming out of the gps are human readable, so you will be able to see if your getting data this way, and then send it be processed after that is working

Comment: @ChadG: In that case, my other (possibly duplicated) post should output the raw data correctly? 

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53963/garbage-output-with-gps-module-gtpa010?noredirect=1#comment112937_53963

Comment: Did changed the baud rate on the other code do any good?

Comment: @ChadG: Surprisingly, no. I'm really clueless now.

Comment: Did you ensure you have the RX/TX pins correct for the GPS? You can swap them in the code without harming anything.

Comment: @ChadG: After a discussion with my team, it seems the GPS module was faulty. I replaced it with a Adafruit Ultimate GPS and now it's working fine :) What a pain!